# Current URL (from address bar) in a Bookmarklet

Tags: php

I'm building a bookmarklet and I need to get the current URL of the webpage the user is on when they activate the bookmarklet.

I tried using

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But that will just get me the URL of the server where the JS for the bookmarklet is hosted. Is there anyway of getting the URL straight from the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the problem by defining your SITE URL (eg: `define('SITE_URL', 'http://abc.com')`) and concat the site url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Eg: `$cur_url = SITE_URL.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply pass `location.href` form the bookmarklet.

For example;

```
location.href="http://mywebsite.com/bookie.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
```

Then on your server, you get the URL at `$_GET['url']`. Good luck.

Of course, that's just JS. You need to add `javascript:` scheme for it to work.

Comment: I don't think that will work because the bookmarklet could be opened on any page.

Comment: Of course it will work. `location.href` gets the URL of the current page, which could be anything.

Comment: **Note:** `http://mywebsite.com/bookie.php?url=` is your **your own** URL, not that of the client's. You need to change it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

If by bookmarklet you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet than I think this code will help:

```
javascript:alert(document.location.href);
```

To test it, select the code and drag it in your bookmark browser bar than click it.